# Gitkraken - when rebasing error "cannot add submodule without HEAD to index"

Tags: gitkraken

I want to rebase in GitKraken, but it does not work and I see this error:

```
Cannot add submodule without HEAD to index
```

But if I do this in Git bash, everything works.

How is that?